# VS2017 Nuget Packages copied to bin\debug but not bin\release on compile

Tags: compiler-errors, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have 3 Nuget Packages included in my project.  When I build the 'debug' version, the dll's are copied into the bin\debug directory, and the project compiles correctly.

However, when I attempt to build a release version, I get a 'The type or namespace name 'packagename' could not be found.

The project .csproj file is as follows:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\MyProject.XML</DocumentationFile>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\MyProject.XML</DocumentationFile>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Excel, Version=2.1.2.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93517dbe6a4012fa, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I am getting the same error message for all three pages, and they only errors I get are related to these not existing.  There are no other compile errors.

For each of these dll's the path (properties) for the debug version is the  bin\Debug directory, but I do not know how this is being set.

I am not sure how I can get these packages into my bin\release directory (other than copying them manually).  Can someone explain what I have missed, or am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the contents of your packages.config file? Also, did you use the package manager?

Comment: Where does the `HintPath` point to? or is this path property you mentioned? if you can reproduce this from clean project, please share the msbild binary log (`msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /bl` in developer command prompt to create `msbuild.binlog`)

Comment: Are you added those three packages via NuGet? Those reference info are seems to be wrong, `HintPath` missing, package name and version are not matched. I can not find any of these three packages on nuget.org. So you should provide more detail steps so that we could reproduce this issue.

Comment: @Lorettac242, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, you can try to remove those `<Reference Include="` items and uninstall those packages. Then re-install those packages, check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses.  I have resolved the issue and improved my understanding of how this all works.

Nuget will get the packages and put them into the packages directory in the solution directory.  It will also add the following packages.config file to the solution directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" version="2.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ExcelDataReader" version="2.1.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

The 'HintPath' in the .csproj file.  This is used by the compiler, providing the source location for the assembly files, which are copied to the relevent bin\Debug or bin\Release directory, as required:

```
 <ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>packages\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.5\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Excel, Version=2.1.2.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93517dbe6a4012fa, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>packages\ExcelDataReader.2.1.2.3\lib\net45\Excel.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <HintPath>packages\SharpZipLib.0.86.0\lib\20\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

My issues was that I had removed the 'HintPath' as it was pointing to the wrong directly, and then nothing worked.  The assemblies in my bin\Debug where there from building a debug version referencing the wrong set of assembly files.  The above code blocks now work correctly.